# How to accomplish topology with OpenNMS

Tags: linux, topology, opennms

I want to use `OpenNMS` and test `Linkd layer 2 iso/osi model network topology discovery`. But I can't find `linkd daemon` after starting OpenNMS, and there is no configuration file `linkd-configuration.xml`. The instruction page is https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Linkd

Comment: @Rai Sorry to trouble you .I can't find `linkd-configuration.xml` in `/usr/share/opennms/etc` directory. I create a requisition and add node with local ip. But the `topology` in the webpage only shows one host: the local. And no other hosts discovered in the local network. How can I make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Linkd was removed in OpenNMS Horizon 16.  The new daemon is Enlinkd (enhanced linkd).  You can find the configuration in etc/enlinkd-configuration.xml.  It is  similar to the old linkd configuration.  see notes at https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Map_Use_Cases_2015#Linkd_and_EnLinkd

Don't forget to enable the Enlinkd daemon if it isn't in service-configuration.xml.

I've also updated the Linkd wiki page with a note.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I configure enlinkd-configuration.xml to make opennms show correct topology?I haven't found how to change enlinkd-configuration.xml.

Comment: How can I configure `enlinkd-configuration.xml` to discover topology? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for the "Enhanced Linkd" daemon can be found here: http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/17.1.1/guide-admin/#ga-enlinkd